# how to give boarder to the text box using Tkinter.I have tryed giving bg as some value but still not able to see the boarder appearing

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

```
#Creating GUI with tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0",'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config( font=("Verdana", 15 ,'bold'),fg='green')

        res = chatbot_response(msg)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "MyBot:: " + res + '\n\n')

        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)

base = Tk()
base.title("Hello")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#Create Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bg="#CCD1D1", height="8", width="50", font="Arial")

ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

#Bind scrollbar to Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

#Create Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Verdana",15,'bold'), text="Enter", width="12", height=10,
                    bd=10, bg='green', fg='#58D68D',
                    command= send )

#Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bg="#CCD1D1",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")

#Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376,y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6,y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)

base.mainloop()
```

## How Can I add boarder to the input text space ?

## I have tried giving bg=4 or bg=5 but still not able to see the boarder appearing.

## How can I fix this issue and also how I can put some colour on Enter button?

Comment: You've posted too much code. If the question is about a border on a widget, we only need to see the widget, the code you're using to add the border, and enough other code to make it work. We don't need a bunch of other widgets. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`bg` is for the background color, not the border. You need to use the `borderwidth` (or `bd`) and/or `relief` options.